# How to run VisualVM Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, visualvm

I am trying to run Visual Plugin in Eclipse Juno. Visual VM usage instructions are confusing. Running my application on Tomcat server and I have no idea how to point it to Visual VM.

**Usage Instructions:**

1. Create a new application configuration
2. Choose the "VisualVM Launcher" as the application launcher
3. Run/Debug the application with the created configuration to have VisualVM started automatically.

How would I choose Visual VM Launcher for my application which is running on Tomcat?

Comment: See also this question for how to have the application show by name in visualvm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433979/how-do-i-give-a-name-to-a-visualvm-unknown-application/4436208#4436208

Comment: please refer this doc https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/05/setting-up-visualvm-in-under-5-minutes/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [VisualVM plugin for Eclipse](https://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html) is only useful when you can start the application from within Eclipse (i.e. when it's a plain Java application, not Tomcat or something that is to be deployed in Tomcat).

In your case, just start `jvisualvm` (which you can find the same folder as `javac`) and select the Tomcat process in the dialog.

Note that you may have to [configure Tomcat to allow VisualVM to connect](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html).

Alternatively, you can create a launch config for Tomcat but to do this, you will have to read the startup files, collect all JARs that have to go into the classpath manually **and** correctly, collect startup parameters, use the correct "current directory", set a couple of system properties ... it's possible but you probably don't want to try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I started jvisualvm I can see the tomcat in VisualVM. But I can't find any of my MBeans there. Note: Using JDK1.6

Comment: That's a new question. Ask it with an example how one of your MBean looks like and how you register it.